# How to update images in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I have a RecyclerView of images that the user is able to edit directly in the RecyclerView itself.

The editing part is fine and works well. It's done on a bitmap that overlays the images and then saves any changes to the image file. As soon as the user scrolls the recyclerview, the bitmap is destroyed and becomes invisible.

The trouble is, any changes the user makes aren't visible when they scroll. They scroll the OLD image, not the EDITED image. They have to get out of the recycler and back into it to see the changes.

So how do I force the RecyclerView to reload the image that was just saved. I'm using Glide in my adapter, and as you can see I have the caching based on the save time of the image.

```
class InfinityPageAdapter(val memo: Memo) : ListAdapter<Page, InfinityPageAdapter.ViewHolder>(PageDiffCallback()) {

  class ViewHolder(pageView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(pageView)

  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): InfinityPageAdapter.ViewHolder {
    val pageView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.infinity_page_list_item, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(pageView)
  }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val page = getItem(position)

    val imageUrl = getMemoPath(memo.uuid) + page.uuid + ".webp"
    if (imageUrl.isNotEmpty()) {
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
                .load(imageUrl)
                .apply(RequestOptions()
                        .signature(ObjectKey(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
                        .override(memo.pageWidth,memo.pageHeight)
                )
                .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                .into(holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.memo_page_image))
    }
  }
```

Is there a way to notify the recyclerview that the image has changed, and force a reload of the image?

I'm using DiffUtil on the adapter. My understanding is, I don't need to use notifyDataSetChanged() when you're using DiffUtil. But I don't understand how you notify of an image change.

I don't know whether the Diff Callback is the issue. For what it's worth, here it is. It doesn't look at the image file itself, just the name of the image file. It might be that, because the name isn't changing, the image doesn't update. But I don't want to be changing the name of the file with every edit.

```
class PageDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Page>() {

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Page, newItem: Page): Boolean {
    return oldItem.id == newItem.id
  }

  override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Page, newItem: Page): Boolean {
    return oldItem == newItem
  }
}
```

thanks!

John

Answer (score 0):

This thing is, you are not updating an entire element in your recycler view, this is, a row. The notifyDataSetChanged() will force the data update like you said, but in this case it will also update your layout.

With DiffUtil, besides contents you are also comparing if the items are the same, which they are, since you are comparing their ID, and that isn't changing when you update your image.

Before trying with notifyDataSetChanged() tho, could you try to do this in your `areContentsTheSame()`method:

```
override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Page, newItem: Page): Boolean {
return oldItem.id == newItem.id && oldItem.image == newItem.image // If you want just add more validations here
}
```

Comment: I tried adding a timestamp field `lastUpdated` to the data, and I changed the `areContentsTheSame` differ to read `return oldItem.id == newItem.id && oldItem.lastUpdated == newItem.lastUpdated` but it still doesn't seem to trigger a refresh of `onBindViewHolder` which is where I am expecting to see the action. Rather than using `notifyDataSetChanged()` I'm using `submitList()`, which triggers the differ callback but interestingly the timestamp on oldItem is the same as the timeStamp on newItem, which may be why the view doesn't recycle and onBindViewHolder doesn't get called.